# Count HTTP requests on a Windows IaaS

Tags: amazon-web-services

A customer-specific instance is billed by volume of submitted requests.

Is there an Amazon API to count HTTP requests?

I am looking at http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/ but it does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ELB you can turn on ELB logs and process the logs to count requests. If not, you can send request metadata to Kinesis and process that stream